# Does LSTM cell update take into account the current input?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, nlp, lstm

I have a question raised by studing LSTM. At the following [link](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/) I found a very useful explaination of the LSTM mechanism. Parts and equations from this blog post have been reported in several other webpages about LSTM (including Wikipedia). However, by reading the original [paper](http://www.bioinf.jku.at/publications/older/2604.pdf) of LSTM there is something that doesn't match. My question is about the update of the cell'state. In the blog it is defined by the equation that defines C<sub>t</sub>, this equation takes into account either the last output h<sub>t-1</sub> and the current input x<sub>t</sub>. 
[image]

In the paper, equation (6) tells me that the state at time t  s(t)<sub>c</sub> depends on the element g(net<sub>c</sub>(t)), that is the analog of C<sup>~</sup> of the blog equation. The equation (6) is the following (the term y<sup>in</sup> is the input gate).

[image]

As you can see from the above figures, C<sup>~</sup> depends on both the previous output h and the current input x. However, net<sub>c</sub>(t) in the paper doesn't take into account the current input x<sub>t</sub>. 
Indeed the definition of  net<sub>c</sub>(t) is the following (equation 4 in the paper).

[image]

where y<sup>u</sup>(t-1) is the output value of unit u at time t-1.

So my question is about if there is an error in the paper or in the blog. Since The blog's version is the one I've often found in courses, tutorials, and all practical material including tensorflow implementation!

Note that the same question raises about the computation of the input gate i<sub>t</sub>.

PS. the cited paper is the first about LSTM, the forget gate has been introduced by another paper, however the mentioned equations are the same in both papers.